# Combining Ready! API Test Case Properties in Groovy

Tags: groovy, ui-testing

Just starting to learn ReadyApi and Groovy, 
I would like to combine 3 project properties into a single property using a Groovy Script as a step in my SoapUI test:

```
Prop1 = "\\ap52\x$"
Prop2 = "\folder1\folder2\"
Prop3 = "1234567890123456"
```

Where:

- Prop1 is a net resource which could change
- Prop2 is a Folder location which is unlikely to change
- Prop3 is actually a random 16 digit number generated and populated into Prop3 from another step

I need PropX to be created so I can transfer the property into a File Wait step.

Desired result of script with static text:

```
PropX = "\\ap52\x$\folder1\folder2\filename_1234567890123456_??????????.xml"
```

Comment: found it on my own

    def string1 = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("Prop1");
    def string2 = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("Prop2");
    def string3 = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("Prop3");
    testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("fileWaitLoc", string1 + string2 + "response_" + string3 + "_??????????.xml")

Comment: Please submit your commentary as an answer. Self-answers are OK. Plus, in answer you can use code formatting.

Comment: I am not a Groovy specialist, but `\"` seems suspicious. Are you sure its not `\\"` or `/"`?

Answer (score 0):

The basic environment for dynamically generating Ready! API test case properties with Groovy are [Ready! API Dynamic Properties](http://readyapi.smartbear.com/glossary/terms/d/dynamic_properties), [Property Expansions](http://readyapi.smartbear.com/features/expansions/start) and [Variable Access in Groovy Script Steps](http://readyapi.smartbear.com/features/scripts/samples/variable).

Since the script will be executed dynamically, you need not worry about the context in which the underlying property values change. Therefore, string concatenation of property values is a feasible approach.

As [demonstrated elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11359333), your best bet for efficient string concatenation in Groovy is to avoid the Java-ish `+`-based approach and unleash the power of [GString interpolation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_string_interpolation):

```
def prop1 = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue('Prop‌​1');
def prop2 = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue('Prop‌​2');
def prop3 = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue('Prop‌​3');
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue('file‌​WaitLoc', "${prop1}${prop2}response_${prop3}_??????????.xml")
```

Comment: Why have you add the [tag:coded-ui-tests] tag to the question? There is nothing in the question about Coded UI or about the Visual Studio that is used to create and run such tests.

Comment: @AdrianHHH I'm sorry. It was beyond my imagination that a general tag name would be exclusive to a specific tool. I should have read the tag description more carefully. I have exchanged the tag. Thank you for your friendly hint.

Answer (score 0):

found it on my own ...

```
def string1 = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("Prop‌​1"); 
def string2 = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("Prop‌​2"); 
def string3 = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("Prop‌​3"); 
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("file‌​WaitLoc", string1 + string2 + "response_" + string3 + "_??????????.xml")
```

However, this still did not work when sending this propertyvalue to the "Wait File" step in ReadyAPI ... it doesnt like the wildcard usage in the fileName, i.e. "??????????".
I had to have development remove the added characters used for the unique naming in the file name in order for the File Wait step to work.